# Fetch data using scrapy.FormRequest in aspx

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new in Python and scrapy. I have a project to fetch data from a aspx webpages and store the values. There are 1000 pages like this that should I fetch the values everydays. it seems easy but I couldn't do it.

this is the webpage http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35366681030756042 that I should scrape! I look at the code from chrome [image]

the red box is updating everyday, this is the the sourepage

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />
</div>
    
<div id="tabs" class="InsInfoTab"></div>
<div id="MainBox" class="box1 zFull silver">
<div id="MainContent" class="tabcontent content">

<div id="TopBox"></div>
```

all data that i need included in TobBox ,

The network tab in chrome shows the data translation but there is not the information that i want to fetch
[image]

I prefer to use scrapy since I have many pages to fetch everyday . I also used `scrapy.FromRequest` but i didnt get the information of `< div id='topbox' ...>` that i want! which means the data that I get is something esle forexample one of the valie that i need is `28688000000` but the data from below code is something else.

```
import scrapy
class SpidyQuotes(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidyquotes-viewstate'
    start_urls = ['http://tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35366681030756042']
    download_delay = 1.5
    
    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
        return scrapy.FormRequest(
                'http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=35366681030756042&c=23%20',               
            )
```

Comment: If you are looking for a GET method there is no reason to use `scrapy.FormRequest`. Can you make some updates in your pictures like making a circle to show what do you really want to scrap ?

Comment: @AvyWam Thanks for your comment, i updated the question. my code fetch something else from this page not the information that I need , how to get all data of tobBox from this page ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't set up a scrapy project for this, but could you try it anyhow?

```
import requests

headers = {
    "referer": "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35366681030756042",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
print(requests.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=35366681030756042&c=23%20", headers=headers).text)
```

Output:

```
12:30:00,A ,22860,22500,22600,23040,23500,21890,29025,107770816,2424554373560,1,20201111,123000;;44@121810@22850@22850@254506@60,2@2400@22840@22860@4652@6,3@36529@22810@22880@629@1,;95523,610991,381092;;;;0;
```

Which kinda looks like your data.

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure this is the data you're after. Some parts of the table *might* be static, but I'm not 100% sure. However, the response depends on the time you make it. Give it a try a few times and you'll get different results.

For example:

```
12:29:59,A ,23620,23540,23100,22500,23620,23100,6812,32872444,773767679280,0,20201114,122959;99/8/24 13:31:11,F,1247591.37,<div class='pn'>26516.85</div> 2.17%,47421383985982830,5039085007,61918112976496,730494,P,2229923171,42233712134879,761621,P,2247810,86754663785,3726,;1980@12346584@23620@23660@434@1,11@7181@23610@23700@4000@2,28@61104@23600@23790@2000@1,;95579,611671,381092;31872444,1000000,0,20603084,12269360,2242,1,0,3575,8;;;0;
```

Also, you can get the entire `.csv` file with historical data.

Here's how:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "referer": "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35366681030756042",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

export_url = "http://tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=35366681030756042"
export = requests.get(export_url, headers=headers).text

with open("oil_data.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(export)
```

And this is what you get back:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but u know the data that i want is different, for example, there is no 28688000000 value, i updated my question, kindly please look again. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, some values are shown in your code and some values are not !, if you look at the circle there is a circle, those values are not fetched using your code, how to fetch them?

Comment: @Ehsan the informations presented in the smaller circle are available in the source code clearly: exact xpath `/html/body/div[4]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div`. You use to much the `Network` tab, use the `Inspector` tab then in the search bar look for the values you want: figures or arabic words.

Comment: im confused, inspect element and source code page is different, `page = requests.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35366681030756042",headers=headers).text doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page)  txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]')` shows emoty string @AvyWam